# How to design a Silver light user control by using mouse drag and drop ? Not by adjusting from xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight

Well,I am trying to do something similar what I did in Adobe Flex.Consuming a web service from Silverlight application and display the result.But the problem is make the UI in silverlight I found it tiresome and not convenient for me.Is it possible to design the UI using drag and drop easily ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 (currently in Release Candidate version) supports drag-and-drop editing of Silverlight 3.

Update: Visual Studio 2010 has been released and Silverlight is on version 4.

Comment: Thank you again. I am using VS2010 Professional to work with it.

Answer (score 4):

The best designer friendly visual tool from Microsoft to do this is Expression Blend. WHile it supports direct editing of the XAML file, 99% of the time you will be working on the visual surface using the mouse to drag and drop, re-size etc.

Comment: @JohnnyBoats- This means VS doesn't support drag and drop ?

Comment: When Visual Studio 2010 ships in a couple of months you can expect good WYSIWYG editing for XAML. The Silverlight support in the Release Candidate is a complicated story as it does not support Silverlight 4, you need the Beta 2 version of Visual Studio 2010 for that.

SO for right now (March 2010) Expression Blend is your best choice for WYSIWYG editing of Silverlight XAML.